# How to ignore "script" in url?

Tags: security, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP.

I have following url to call my application:

```
http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay
```

This works great and it calles index.jsp as per my expectations.

But if my request url is changed as:

```
http://machine.domain.com:8383/eqube70/BuildNPlay/?--%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('you got hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

Then I get the alert and  I am not able to get my application working.
This is probably script in the request url gets executed.

Now I want some way to ignore script in the URL before it gets passed to the JSP.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: How are you processing query string parameters for this specific page?

Comment: Your problem is much more general than just script. You appear to be embedding an argument supplied by the user inside the page you're returning. You need to consider the security aspects of that from all angles, not just script.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick way you can run all your input parameters through a function that replaces all < and > with something else.

```
private String replaceGTLT(String str)
{
   if(str==null) return null;
   return str.replaceAll("<", "[").replaceAll(">", "]");
}

String parameterX = replaceGTLT(request.getParameter("parameterX"));
```

Of course, `[script]alert('you got hacked')[/script]` will still be in the input, but it won't run in the browser due to changing the angular brackets to square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use scriptlets, JSTL escapes stuff for you.
2. Be very careful with the `param` implicit EL object. That could be user supplied. You can use `escapeXml` from JSTL to escape stuff.
3. You could write a ServletFilter [(info here)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to filter out stuff you don´t want before they touch your webapp.
4. In the end, you want a Framework with solid XSS prevention stuff. Check [this list](http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/10-best-java-web-development-framework/)